Text Files vs. Binary Files
I am reading "Computer Systems: A Programmer's Perspective", and there are two statements that, when taken together, don't make sense to me:

The hello.c program is stored in a file as a sequence of bytes.
Files such as hello.c that consist exclusively of ASCII characters are known as text files. All other files are known as binary files.

If a file is stored as a sequence of bytes, then it is stored as a sequence of numbers from 0 to 255. Each number from 0 to 255 is a valid ASCII character (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), so how it is possible to create a file that consists of anything other than valid ASCII characters?

You're right - the distinction is neither accurate nor important.

The text probably means to exclude the "extended ascii" part (codes 128-255). Still not an accurate or particularly useful distinction. Character encoding is a hairy topic that this comment is unlikely to do justice to. Nods to the EBCDIC gang.

It should probably be ASCII characters 9, 10, 13 and 32-126 only. But even then, it's a bit fuzzy, because there are other text encodings beyond ASCII. Usually, a text file means a file that contains only human-readable text in some encoding, while binary files (also) contain bytes that don't directly represent text but something else and are to be interpreted by their numeric or binary values instead. So for example the number 26 (decimal) stored as bytes 0x32 0x36 (ASCII) would be text but as byte 0x1A it would be a binary representation.

the book you're reading seems to assume that all text files are encoded in ascii, which is far from being true

The author's statement implies that the sequence of ASCII characters is a human readable text, because the purpose of ASCII is the text encoding. Although it's not explicitly stated.

(Unextended) ASCII goes from 0 to 127, not to 255.  ASCII includes codes which are not printable characters. For instance code 0 is the NUL character, but when it's present in a file, that tends to identify it as a binary file.
Text files consist of only nonblank and blank printable characters and some format control characters like carriage returns, linefeeds, vertical tabs and form feeds.
A file with bytes in the range 127 to 255 could be text: it could be some extended ASCII like a variant of ISO Latin, or it could be UTF-8-encoded Unicode.
Text files omit most of the characters below 32.

The wording in the book is unclear and unhelpful. They mean consisting of printable ASCII characters. ASCII text files (for English) consist almost entirely of characters in the range 0x20-0x7e plus 0x09 (tab), 0x0A (linefeed) and 0x0D. Many DOS/Windows plain text files also terminate with a 0x1A (^Z) character even today.
The distinction between a text file and a binary file is a throwback to the antediluvian days of CP/M when files were always a multiple of 128 byte records long and an EOF character ^Z (0x1A) was used to terminate a text file (and often still is in some Windows software). It was retained in MS DOS for backwards compatibility.
The EOF character used in ASCII text files was a menace back in the days of command line COPY commands which defaulted to text mode so that any attempt to copy an executable or binary file would be truncated at the first ^Z it encountered. A trap for the unwary that caused much grief.
There is a meaningful distinction between text (or more restrictive numerical text) data files and binary files in that the latter may use any and all of the possible byte values (so will classic ASCII text in French or Italian).
If you make a histogram of the frequency of the bytes in a file then you can get a quick measure and so a heuristic of what it is likely to be and how well compressed it is (or more accurately how compressible it remains). The byte entropy is a nice measure of how well the available symbols have been used.
Numeric UTF16 ~ 1.8 (half of all bytes are 0)
Numeric TXT ~ 2
TXT  ~ 2-3
BMP ~ 3
MIME, OBJ ~ 4
PNG, JPEG, XLS, ZIP ~ 5.4

The maximum possible entropy for a file using all 256 symbols equally often is log(256) 5.545. A typical ASCI text file of readable text uses around 80 symbols (max ~99) but some of them very infrequently. The theoretical highest entropy of a printable ASCII text file could be ~4.6 log(99). This is a toy program that can allow you to distinguish file contents based on the histogram and its entropy.
#include <iostream>
#include "stdio.h"
#include "math.h"

double entropy(int* hist, int N)
{
    double x, sumx, s;
    sumx = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) sumx += hist[i];
    s = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (hist[i])
        {
            x = hist[i]/sumx;
            s -= x * log(x);
        }
    return s;
}

void showhist(int* hist, int N, int verbose)
{
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        if (hist[i] || verbose)
        {
            printf("%3i : %-9i\n", i, hist[i]);
            count++;
        }
    printf("\nSymbols used %i/256\n", count);
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *fin;
    int hist[256], length = 0;

    if (argc == 1) printf("Usage: sfile <filename>\n");
    else
       fopen_s(&fin, argv[1], "rb");
       if (fin == NULL) 
       {
         printf("File %s not found\n", argv[1]);  return -1;
       }
       for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) hist[i] = 0;
       while (!feof(fin))
       {
          unsigned char c;
          c = getc(fin);
          hist[c]++;
          length++;
       }
       fclose(fin);
       printf("Filename %s loaded. %i bytes read\n\nHistogram\nByte  Frequency\n", argv[1], length);
       showhist(hist, 256, 0);
       printf("\nByte entropy s = %3.6f\n", entropy(hist, 256));
 }

Applying this entropy heuristic to blocks of orphaned data is one way to help find and recover damaged JPEG or other highly compressed binary files.
